# Concurrent document collaboration on local servers

Tags: collaboration, document-management, cloud-service, office

Does a concurrent office document collaboration service exist that does not rely on 3rd party servers?

By "collaboration" I mean changes made to a document are quickly visible to others that have the document open.

Office 365 and Google Docs have nice collaboration features, but they require use of their servers.