# Online Collaboration Tool

Tags: collaboration

I am looking for a **cloud-based**, off-premise solution to housing files (that are currently Excel spreadsheets) to allow:

- Real-time editing of data with multiple connections;
- Reporting functionality, similar to "Graphs" in Excel;
- Support common excel queries/formulas such as `=A1:A14/B1` and other functions

Further items I would like to see are:

- Autonomous backups;
- Version control and history;
- Support macro or other scripting engines to allow data to be manipulated

Being cloud based, I would prefer it to be accessible via a Web Interface, but will settle for a Windows Based application.

**Current solutions**

Currently we are trialing Excel Online and storing the data within a OneDrive account, however we find that simultaneous editing, and macros are not as "smooth" as we'd hoped.

Another option is [Spreadsheets In Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.valiantys.spreadsheets/cloud/pricing), which may meet the requirements.

**Note:** We currently pay for both Atlassian and Office 365.

Similarly based questions:

- [Concurrent document collaboration on local servers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/43656/concurrent-document-collaboration-on-local-servers)

Comment: IIRC, "Real-time editing of data with multiple connections" and "Excel" don't go well together – unless that has changed lately. Simultaneously editing the same Excel file proved problematic even on "local network shares" in the past – which is not a fault of the network. So another storage is unlikely to solve that. Not sure if a 3rd party tool capable of editing Excel files will solve that – but good luck!

Comment: @Izzy You remember correctly, which is why we're migrating away from Excel to another solution. Essentially you summarized it: *3rd party tool capable of editing Excel files*

Comment: Would you care to name said "3rd party tool capable of editing Excel files" to help others?

Comment: @Mawg Option was linked, *Spreadsheet for Confluence* ;) I am open to try others!

Comment: How on earth did I miss that?!